# Convert irregular date column to standard date format in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working with a dataframe has one `date` column with irregular format, ie:

```
          date
0     1991/1/1
1     1970/1/1
2   1991/01/01
3   1996-01-01
4   1996-06-30
5   1995-12-31
6   1997-01-01
7     1970/1/1
8   1996-01-01
9   1997-01-01
10  1996-01-01
```

How can I convert it to standard format `XXXX-XX-XX`, which represents `year-month-date`.

Use `df.date.unique()`, I get the following output, in fact, I want to view all the unique date values:

```
array(['2017-10-01', '2015-1-1', '2008-06-01', ...,
       datetime.datetime(2005, 2, 1, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2004, 5, 1, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 20, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

Use `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`, I get:

```
ValueError: month must be in 1..12
```

Anyone could help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `errors='coerce'`

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df.date,errors='coerce')
```

For those line return `nan` , we may need check it one by one , since it is special case. However, the idea here is

```
df['Date']=np.where(df['Date'].isnull(), pd.to_datetime(df.date,format='something here'),df['Date'])
```

Comment: Some `date` cells in excel file are empty, so I think it's normal, isn't it?

Comment: Another question, do you know how to view all values from `df.date.unique()`, I try with `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None), pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)`, doesn't work out.

Comment: @ahbon you have too many unique date , I will recommend save it as excel or csv to review it .